# What are the voice commands for Xbox 360's Kinect?

Tags: kinect

I recently purchased Kinect, and was curious if there is a place to find all of the voice commands for the system?

The manual doesn't really say a lot about the voice commands and I can't find a definative list of all the commands I can use.

The Xbox prompts with some commands now and then, but it would be really nice to have an actual list of things I can tell it to do.

Help?

Comment: Sudo make me a sandwich

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Official List](http://support.xbox.com/en-us/pages/kinect/more-topics/control-your-xbox-360-with-your-voice.aspx)

... which is very small. Not many have been found that are not on that list, but "ESPN" is one for example, that can bring you to the ESPN page while on the dashboard. Microsoft has stated it is up the the individual game / app maker for functionality, and that they *should* provide a list that can be used with their services.

At one point it was demo'd that you could turn on / turn off the machine using voice commands. This functionality however did not make it to release (for obvious reasons).

Comment: I still wish I could power on/off the Xbox with voice commands.  I wish Xbox would have exposed an setting to allow us to turn this option on or off.  I heard Lauralolipop (on twitter) mention that the Xbox wants to be green and not consume power to listen for verbal commands.

Comment: you can power off ("Xbox Settings", "turn off", and then "yes") but can't power on.